# Why will my tkinter.Toplevel widget not appear?

Tags: tkinter, toplevel

I would like for a `tkinter` window to open after my program sleeps for 5 seconds.  On this window, there should be a countdown, starting from 10 seconds.  Once the countdown reaches 0, the window should close.  This process should continue endlessly.  I do not understand why my `Toplevel` widget is not appearing.

I am trying to use a `Toplevel` because as far as I understand if I use the root, my `Tk()` that is, once I call the `mainloop()` method the code is blocked, and therefore destroying the root would end the program.

As of now, the toplevel does not appear, but the function  `countdown_gui()` is called.

Does the root not entering the `mainloop` cause this issue somehow?  And if so, how would I run call the `mainloop` without blocking?  Is threading the only solution?

```py
# Wait 5 seconds, open a countdown window for a 10 second countdown
# close the window and repeat

import time
import tkinter

def countdown_gui():
    """Display an updating countdown."""

    def update_countdown():
        """Update the label by reducing the value by 1."""

        current_second = int(timer["text"])
        timer.config(text = current_second - 1)

        # The function calls itself, so it will update every second
        timer.after(
            ms = 1000,
            func = update_countdown
            )

        # Destroy everything once the countdown reaches the end
        if current_second == 0:
            toplevel.destroy()

    # Create the toplevel
    toplevel = tkinter.Toplevel(master = root)

    # The label displaying the seconds
    timer = tkinter.Label(
        master = toplevel,
        text = 10
        )
    timer.pack()

    # As soon as the label is created, start counting down
    timer.after(
        ms = 1000,
        func = update_countdown
        )

root = tkinter.Tk()

while True:
    print("sleeping...")
    time.sleep(5)
    countdown_gui()
```

Comment: `mainloop()` is not executed.

Comment: @acw1668 Where would you put it?  And how would I get around the issue of `mainloop()` blocking my code?

Comment: Actually you need to call `root.wait_window(toplevel)` at the end of `countdown_gui()`.

Comment: That fixed the issue.  Thank you.  To clarify, `root.mainloop()` was never called, and the only change was adding `root.wait_window(toplevel)` at the end of `countdown_gui()`